# sub UL class (CSS styling)

Tags: css

I ran into a problem with CSS and can't solve it. Currently I try to rework my page (http://backlight.around-the-globe.info/) and would like to style the dropdown menu on the top. My goal is to make  the flyout transparent and leave the rest at it is (Africa should be white, Hurghada semi-transparent). . This is what I've got so far but it makes the whole nav bar transparent.

```
nav ul, nav li, .page__tray ul.menu-item-has-children li {
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 );
}

.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li {
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 );
}
```

I know  this code is wrong but I don't get the right solution.

Comment: i'm guessing u need the whole nav bar to be in white.?

Comment: exactly, nav bar in white and the drop-down item in "semi-transparent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at your issue following solution should work:

You need to include the below CSS:

```
.primary-menu { background:white; }
```

Changed Opacity value from 0 to 0.67 giving it a semi-transparent look:

```
.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm but I still have a question. I still need the first block starting with to get this working and I dont know why. Why is this

--> nav ul, nav li, .page__tray ul.menu-item-has-children li {
    background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0 );
} <---

still necessarry? (I cant format the code properly, sry)

Comment: removing it will result in **nav li**  being solid white, Forcing its children to be solid white. if its not neccessary remove it and include  **background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);**  to **.sub-menu**. This should work. Accept the answer if you are satisfied.